# Disable date selection is not working -jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have the following code 
but it is not working for some reason 
first 1 is working bt the second input box is not working where i want to disable few dates.

it is working fine on fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CxNNh/1/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

var array = ["2013-03-14","2013-03-15","2013-03-16"]

$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});



$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<input />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**i solved myself and thought it would be helpful to some1  as there are many views but no 1 could  answer**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> by Suraj Mishra</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>



 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">


 <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 


$(window).load(function(){



var array = ["2014-01-11","2014-01-12","2014-01-10"]

$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
});


//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <input />

</body>


</html>
```